# Show the spectral radius of a matrix is smaller than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\hat{\bf H}$ be a $p\hat{N}\times p \hat{N}$ sparse matrix consisting of $p\times p$ blocks, where each block is of size $\hat{N}\times\hat{N}$. The values in $\hat{\bf H}$ is illustrated below (empty places are zero):

> [image]

The infinite norm of $\hat{\bf H}$ is obviously 1, and I know spectral radius is no larger than any natural norm. My question is how do I prove the spectral radius of this matrix is smaller than 1?

I did a simple numerical experiment, and found the claim should hold. If $p \to \infty$ and $\hat{N} \to \infty$, then the spectral radius should approach to 1.

If we fix $p = 5$ and let $\hat{N}$ go from 5 to 100, we have

> [image]

If we fix $\hat{N} = 10$ and let $p$ go from 5 to 100, we have

> [image]

Comment: I don't understand the pattern of the matrix $\hat H$, could you give and example with $N=1$ and $p=6$ ? and then with $N=2$ and $p=2$ ?

Comment: Thanks. If $\hat{N}=1$ and $p=6$, then $\hat{\mathbf{H}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{\rm{1}}&{}&{}&{}&{}\\
{\rm{1}}&{}&{\rm{1}}&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{\rm{1}}&{}&{\rm{1}}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{\rm{1}}&{}&{\rm{1}}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&{\rm{1}}&{}&{\rm{1}}\\
{}&{}&{}&{}&{\rm{1}}&{}
\end{array}} \right)$. If $\hat{N}=2$ and $p=2$, I think the matrix is $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}&{\rm{1}}&{}\\
{}&{}&{\rm{2}}&{}\\
{}&{\rm{2}}&{}&{}\\
{}&{\rm{1}}&{}&{}
\end{array}} \right)$

Comment: Ok, perfect for the p=6 example, for the other one, I'm still confused, could you place all the zeroes ? Are the blocs diagonal ?

Comment: Sure. I think it is $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\rm{0}}&{\rm{0}}&{\rm{1}}&{\rm{0}}\\
{\rm{0}}&{\rm{0}}&{\rm{2}}&{\rm{0}}\\
{\rm{0}}&{\rm{2}}&{\rm{0}}&{\rm{0}}\\
{\rm{0}}&{\rm{1}}&{\rm{0}}&{\rm{0}}
\end{array}} \right)$ with zeros. Looks not exactly block diagonal.